# h In Python, how to create a list that separates depending on how many elements you want to combine

Tags: python-3.x, list

Forexample, if i were that have an array such as i = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
I want to separate them into i = [123,456,789]

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share example code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

# set the number of numbers that you want to have "concatenated"
num = 3

# initialise a new list
l_bis = []

# iterate over each pieces of the list that contain three digits
for i in range(len(l)//num):
    # append the new integer after having joined strings of the original integers
    l_bis.append(int("".join([str(x) for x in l[i*num:i*num+num]])))

print(l_bis)
# [123,456,789]
```

Please note that this approach will only work when the length of the initial list is a multiple of the variable `num`!